# Expanding a partition in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, disk-usage

This is what GParted displays about my partitions.

[image: Screenshot from GParted]

And this is the output from `df`:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       61409452 4503052  53786836   8% /
udev              499168       4    499164   1% /dev
tmpfs             203192     784    202408   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none              507972      88    507884   1% /run/shm
```

How do I expand `sda1` by the amount of the unallocated space so that it's size be 160 GiB? Can't find a way so far. "Resize/Move" and "Delete" items in the right-click menus appear grayed out for all the partitions.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question. Can you not right click on `/dev/sda2`, choose 'resize/move', and then shunt it along the disk? And then resize `/dev/sda1` up to the remaining space? Or just remove and recreate `/dev/sda2`, after expanding `/dev/sda1` (it's only swap you've got in there, after all)?

Comment: +1 to the above; Considering your particular setup I think it's easier to:

 1. remove the swap partition sda5 (unmount it prior to removing it)
 2. delete the extended partition sda2
 3. enlarge sda1 as you please
 4. recreate the swap partition and any other additional partitions, either in an extended container or as primary ones(no more than four)

Comment: @ire_and_curses "Resize/Move" is grayed out for any partition, same with "Delete". Made the edit to mention that. Would it make the difference if I boot from Live CD? (Sorry, I'm pretty much new to Linux.)

Comment: @don_crissti Please see my comment on the ire_and_curses' comment.

Comment: @DesmondHume - yes, boot from the livecd, UNMOUNT your partitions then proceed to resize/remove/recreate as per your taste

Comment: @JariLaamanen - he shouldn't be able to start gParted without being root, at least from my experience.

Comment: @don_crissti yes, I realized that right away and withdrew my comment. I +1 your comment, as that most likely is the problem.

Comment: @don_crissti Ok, thank you. Just was relying on my previous history with PartitionMagic (on Windows). The tricky little thing was able to expand partitions without any (prerequisite) reboots.

Comment: @Desmond Hume - Yes, you can't screw around with partitions from your live system! That would be a bit like trying to give *yourself* an appendectomy. You need someone else - a surgeon - to perform the operation for you. In this case, a running environment not dependent on the disk (a live CD).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Gparted to accomplish your task.

**Make sure that you do this from a live CD, to make sure that the drive(s) are unmounted.**

> This article shows how you can modify the partitioning of your Linux
>   system with GParted (Gnome Partition Editor) without losing data. This
>   includes resizing partitions (enlarging and shrinking), moving
>   partitions on the hard drive, creating and deleting partitions, and
>   even modifying filesystem types. GParted is a free partition editor
>   available as a desktop program and also as a Live-CD. It supports the
>   following filesystems: ext2, ext3, fat16, fat32, hfs, hfs+, jfs,
>   linux-swap, reiserfs, reiser4, ufs, xfs, and even ntfs (Windows).
>   [Have alook at this](http://clonezilla.org/)

<sup>Source: [howtoforge](http://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted)</sup>

**NOTE: When dealing with partitions, always make sure that a backup is available in case something goes wrong. You may consider [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)**